# Returning one of different object types from single function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have the following structure at present:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_app_settings")
data class AppSetting(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "app_setting_id")
    val id: Long? = null,

    @Column(name = "app_setting_name")
    val name: String = "",

    @Column(name = "app_setting_value")
    var value: String = "",

    @Column(name = "app_setting_type")
    val type: AppSettingType,
)

enum class AppSettingType {
    CHAR,
    STRING,
    BYTE,
    SHORT,
    INT,
    LONG,
    DOUBLE,
    FLOAT,
    BOOLEAN,
}
```

This is then saved to the database with the following:

```
override fun saveAppSetting(setting: AppSetting): DatabaseResult<AppSetting> {
        log.info("Saving App Setting ${setting.name} to database.")

        return try {
            // Attempt to save the entity to the database. If we do not throw an exception, return success.
            val savedSetting = appSettingsRepository.save(setting)

            DatabaseResult(
                code = ResultCode.CREATION_SUCCESS,
                entity = savedSetting
            )
        } catch(exception: DataAccessException) {
            log.error("Unable to save App Setting ${setting.name} to database. Reason: ${exception.message}")
            DatabaseResult(
                code = ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE
            )
        }
    }
```

Now, let's say that I wish to save a `Char` type to database, I figure I would use the following:

```
override fun saveAppSetting(name: String, value: Char): DatabaseResult<Char> {
        val appSettingResult = saveAppSetting(AppSetting(
            name = name,
            value = value.toString(),
            type = AppSettingType.CHAR,
        ))

        return if(appSettingResult.code != ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE) {
            val entity = getAppSetting<Char>(appSettingResult.entity?.name!!).entity.toString().first()
            DatabaseResult(
                code = appSettingResult.code,
                entity = entity
            )
        } else {
            DatabaseResult(
                code = ResultCode.CREATION_FAILURE,
            )
        }
    }
```

I also figured that I would need to do the following in order to retrieve the correct object type:

```
override fun getAppSetting(name: String): DatabaseResult<Any?> {
        log.info("Getting App Setting $name from database.")
        val appSetting = appSettingsRepository.findAppSettingByName(name)

        return if(appSetting != null) {
            log.info("App Setting $name has ID of ${appSetting.id} within the database")

            when(appSetting.type) {
                AppSettingType.CHAR -> {
                    DatabaseResult<Char>(
                        code = ResultCode.FETCH_SUCCESS,
                        entity = appSetting.value.first(),
                    )
                }
                AppSettingType.STRING -> {
                    DatabaseResult<String>(
                        code = ResultCode.FETCH_SUCCESS,
                        entity = appSetting.value,
                    )
                }
                AppSettingType.BYTE -> {
                    DatabaseResult<Byte>(
                        code = ResultCode.FETCH_SUCCESS,
                        entity = appSetting.value.toByte(),
                    )
                }
                AppSettingType.SHORT -> {
                    DatabaseResult<Short>(
                        code = ResultCode.FETCH_SUCCESS,
                        entity = appSetting.value.toShort(),
                    )
                }
                AppSettingType.INT -> {
                    DatabaseResult<Int>(
                        code = ResultCode.FETCH_SUCCESS,
                        entity = appSetting.value.toInt(),
                    )
                }
                AppSettingType.LONG -> {
                    DatabaseResult<Long>(
                        code = ResultCode.FETCH_SUCCESS,
                        entity = appSetting.value.toLong(),
                    )
                }
                AppSettingType.DOUBLE -> {
                    DatabaseResult<Double>(
                        code = ResultCode.FETCH_SUCCESS,
                        entity = appSetting.value.toDouble(),
                    )
                }
                AppSettingType.FLOAT -> {
                    DatabaseResult<Float>(
                        code = ResultCode.FETCH_SUCCESS,
                        entity = appSetting.value.toFloat()
                    )
                }
                AppSettingType.BOOLEAN -> {
                    DatabaseResult<Boolean>(
                        code = ResultCode.FETCH_SUCCESS,
                        entity = appSetting.value.toBoolean()
                    )
                }
            }
        } else {
            log.error("App Setting $name does not seem to exist within the database.")
            DatabaseResult(
                code = ResultCode.FETCH_FAILURE
            )
        }
```

However, when I then wish to use said object, I still have to write something like the following:

```
val newBarcode = getAppSetting("barcode_value").entity.toString().toInt()
```

Assuming I've "initialised" `barcode_value` with a value of 177 (for example).

How can I get the function to return what I need without having to do `.toString.to...()`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this all possible, here is a simplified demo, firstly

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

data class AppSetting(
   val id: Long? = null,
   val name: String = "",
   var value: String = "",
   val type: AppSettingType,
)

enum class AppSettingType(val clazz: KClass<out Any>) {
   CHAR(Char::class),
   STRING(String::class),
   INT(Int::class),
}
```

So I added a `clazz` so from the enum we know the Kotlin type

and now a function to simulate your repository fetch

```
fun findAppSettingByName(name: String): AppSetting? {
   return when(name) {
      "Char thing" -> AppSetting(value= "C", type = AppSettingType.CHAR)
      "String thing" -> AppSetting(value= "Str", type = AppSettingType.STRING)
      "Int thing" -> AppSetting(value= "42", type = AppSettingType.INT)
      else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
   }
}
```

Next in the function declaration I have made it generic with `T` and for the purposes of the demo removed the `DatabaseResult` container.  Then I added a `clazz` parameter which is the typical Java way of carrying the required class information into the function:

```
fun <T : Any> getAppSetting(name: String, clazz: KClass<T>): T? {
   val appSetting: AppSetting? = findAppSettingByName(name)

   return appSetting?.let {
      require(clazz == appSetting.type.clazz) {
         "appSetting.type=${appSetting.type.clazz} mismatched with requested class=${clazz}"
      }
      when (appSetting.type) {
         AppSettingType.CHAR -> appSetting.value.first()
         AppSettingType.STRING -> appSetting.value
         AppSettingType.INT -> appSetting.value.toInt()
      } as T
   }
}
```

the `as T` is important to cast the values into the required return type - this is unchecked but the when() clause should be creating the correct types.

Now let's test it:

```
   val c1: Char? = getAppSetting("Char thing", Char::class)
   val s1: String? = getAppSetting("String thing", String::class)
   val i1: Int? = getAppSetting("Int thing", Int::class)
   println("c1=$c1 s1=$s1 i1=$i1")

   val c2: Char? = getAppSetting("Char thing")
   val s2: String? = getAppSetting("String thing")
   val i2: Int? = getAppSetting("Int thing")

   println("c2=$c2 s2=$s2 i2=$i2")
}
```

The output is

```
c1=C s1=Str i1=42
c2=C s2=Str i2=42
```

But how do c2/s2/i2 work, the final part is this function

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> getAppSetting(name: String) = getAppSetting(name, T::class)
```

This is reified generic parameters... there is no need to pass the `clazz` because this can be found from the data type of the receiving variable.

There are many articles about this advanced topic, e.g.

- https://typealias.com/guides/getting-real-with-reified-type-parameters/
- https://medium.com/kotlin-thursdays/introduction-to-kotlin-generics-reified-generic-parameters-7643f53ba513

Now, I didn't completely answer what you wanted because you wanted to receive a `DatabaseResult<T>` wrapper.  What might be possible, is to have a function that returns `DatabaseResult<T>` and you can obtain the `T` from it as the "clazz" parameter, but I'll leave that for someone else to improve on :-) but I think that gets you pretty close.